# 'in' operator with boost::python

Tags: python, dictionary, operators, boost-python

I have a class which `.def`ines the `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` methods (and `keys` and `items` as well), and behaves like a dictionary, where keys are strings.

However, the `in` operator does not behave as expected:

```
>>> myObject=MyClass()
>>> 'abc' in myObject.keys()
False
>>> 'abc' in myObject
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.__getitem__(MyClass, int)
did not match the C++ signature:
    __getitem__(MyClass {lvalue}, std::string)
```

Why is python trying to call `__getitem__` with `int`, when I use the `str` key?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) says that "keys should be integers and slice objects".

Comment: The doc you reference mentions explicitly that is only sequences which want integers and slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that

```
'abc' in myObject
```

is being evaluated as:

```
for i in myObject:
    if myObject[i] == 'abc':
        return true
```

Where `i` is an integer.

Try implementing the `__contains__(self, value)` magic method.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I've been grepping docs for `__in__` without success. Thanks!